# Where is the Server Side in GWT Places & Activities?

Tags: java, gwt

If I understand correctly :

- an Activity is a User action on widgets
- This activity moves the application state in another Place
- The url moves along, thanks to anchors (thought modern browsers have an api)
- When we share the url, it define a Place, and it's enough to rebuild the State

(As I'm also a javascript guy, this looks much like Backbone's router and other modern JSFrameworks)

But to rebuild the State, we need to fetch some data to the **Server**. Is there anything in the P&A api to do this ? With RPC, this role is clearly done by GreetingServiceImpl that extends the RemoteServlet. With Backbone, we have the Sync object.

But I never see such code such when I look at A&P tutorials. Where is the Server ? Do we need RPC there ? Does it mix with RequestFactory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a small note about terminology:

A **Place** represents *where you are* in the app. When you look at that screen, it's generally composed of different "blocks", each dedicated to a specific *activity*, e.g.: a header (let's say with search box and logout link), a navigation menu, the "master" in a master-details view, the "details" in a master-details view. All these can be **activities** (though not necessarily, things that are never *swapped* to anything else won't gain anything being activities).

Because activities are by definition displayed on screen, you can interact with them, possibly triggering a move to another place (`PlaceController#goTo`).

The place is optionally *synchronized* with the URL (both ways) and *generate* browser history items; by default using the *hash*, but you can swap the implementation [to use HTML5](https://gist.github.com/tbroyer/1883821).

(places are similar to Backbone's router except they're type-checked, activities are a light layer on top with no equivalent in Backbone AFAICT)

---

Now to answer your question:

GWT is a toolkit, not a framework. That means most building blocks don't force you into using any other building block (places can work without activities, editors can work without widgets, etc.)

Activities start asynchronously, which is where you'd generally get the data from wherever it is. In the spirit of a toolkit, you're free to use whatever fits your needs: GWT-RPC, RequestFactory, RequestBuilder, Errai JAX-RS, Errai Bus, XMLHttpRequest, WebSockets, AppEngine Channels, etc. Some people also post events to their event bus to decouple the activity from how they get their data.

Answer (score 0):

MVP describes the Client-architecture.

**M_odel**:
The business objects handled by you app.

**V_iew**:
UI elements, showing a representation of your model.

**P_resenter**:
A class which handles all userinteractions and modification to your model.

---

Lets assume you have an application which shows and stores Notes.

You have some Places:

- a Place is like an good old HTML page in older days. In `MVP` it can be described a a set of running `Presenter`. In our simple application there are two places. Every `Place` does only have one running `Presenter`

`NotesListPlace` -> shows all stored notes

`NotesEditPlace` -> Creates / Edit a Note

The NotesEditPlace:

There is a View and a Presenter. 
The View has an TextArea (for the Note) and a save button.
The presenter has a clickHandler for the save-button (there may be more, but as example it should be enough)

The User select a Note from the NoteList

`PlaceChange` from `NoteListPlace` -> `NoteEditPlace`

The `Presenter` starts and registers the click-handler at the view. If the button is pressed, the presenter reads the input from the textarea and update the Model (A new Notes-onject)

Now comes the server interaction. You can use every (GWT) transportlayer you want.

The success callback fires a `PlaceChange` event to the `NoteListPlace`.

All starts again. The presenter starts, a new server interacction to load the MOdel ( A List of Notes). The view is updated by the presenter...

*Update 1*
There is no need of a server. The presenter may persist the Model to the localStorage of the browser.

*Update 2*
You can use every  transport mechanism you want. RequestFactory, GWT-RPC. I use RequestBuilder and GWT AutoBeans.

Comment: Places == navigation; Activities == decoupled modularization of "the screen"; MVP != navigation & activities.

Comment: I think, I have to rewrite some parts to be more presize. A place shows a number of Views, each Place controlled by an individual Presenter. If I Navigate to another Place in my App one or mor decoupled Presenter with there views get loaded.

Comment: I just read your answer and I see there is a difference in what I ment and how I wrote it in my answer.